# Sharepoint 2013: Conference room booking with e-mail confirmation?

Tags: exchange

Is this possible? I'd like to create a calendar on sharepoint that users can e-mail in order to reserve a conference room, just like the Room Mailboxes in Exchange. When a user e-mails the room mailbox, they receive a response stating that their reservation is confirmed or declined due to conflict.

Can I do this with Sharepoint or am I better off staying with Exchange for this functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to configure the SharePoint farm to receive incoming email. (ref: [Configure incoming email for a SharePoint 2013 farm](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262947.aspx))

Then you can setup an email-enabled document library. (ref: [Enable and configure e-mail settings for a library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-and-configure-e-mail-support-for-a-list-or-library-dcaf44a0-1d9b-451a-84c7-6c52e7db908e#bmdoclib)) At this stage, email sending to SharePoint mail box will be dropped into this library.

After then you can create a list workflow attached to the email-enabled library. When an email is received, trigger your workflow to analysis the email subject or attachment and then create a reservation request. The requests could be an email sending to boss, or could be a new item adding to a "reservation request" list, or both. It is completely up to your design. (here is a useful ref: [SharePoint 2010: Workflows on Incoming Emails in SharePoint Documents Library](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4607.sharepoint-2010-workflows-on-incoming-emails-in-sharepoint-documents-library.aspx))